# Showing link using Ternary Operator

Tags: java, angularjs, ternary-operator

How can this be achieved in partial html file ?

```
{{x.stringData > 50 ? <a ng-click="showData(x)">...</a> | '' }}
```

Obviously the above is not correct so its just for understanding that what I want to achieve.

Comment: why is this question tagged with `java`?

Comment: Because most who know both `java` and `angularjs` may forget to add tag posts for `angularjs` in their profile. So just in case to cover up, I added this tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `ng-if` attribute.

for example:

```
<a ng-click="showData(x)" ng-if="x.stringData.length > 50">...</a>
```

Resource:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf